# Stopping Probabilities for Random Walk with Drift

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, random-walk

**[EDIT]** After the comments and answer I understood that my formation of the problem is incorrect. However I'm still interested in a stochastic solution to the original riddle. **Please skip to the "Background" part of this question.** And thanks for setting a bounty on this question!!

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be independent and identically distributed random variable. $X_i = 2$ or $X_i=-1$ each with 50% probability. And let $S_n = X_1+\cdots+ X_n$ be the associated random walk. So we can think of this as a random walk with drift $\mu = 0.5$ and step-length = $1.5$

For a given constant $m$, suppose we define a stopping rule to stop when $S_n \leq -m$ or $S_n \geq K$. How do we find $K$, such that the probability of stopping at $S_n \geq K$ is equal to the probability of stopping at $S_n \leq -m$?

When there is no drift the solution is trivial $K = m$. I suspect this little modification should be a classical problem in stochastic process too?

The solution is apparently $K \sim O(m^2)$, but I'm looking for a stochastic explanation. see the background below.

**Background:** I found [this riddle](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/how-many-soldiers-do-you-need-to-beat-the-night-king/) and [its solution](https://www.bhsu.edu/Portals/0/Faculty-Staff/Daniel-Swenson/Riddler/night_king.pdf?ver=2019-05-19-173548-210). I reproduce the riddle here:

> At a pivotal moment in an epic battle between the living and the dead,
> the Night King, head of the army of the dead, raises all the fallen
> (formerly) living soldiers to join his ranks. This ability obviously
> presents a huge military advantage, but how big an advantage exactly?
>
> Forget the Battle of Winterfell and model our battle as follows. Each
> army lines up single file, facing the other army. One soldier steps
> forward from each line and the pair duels — half the time the living
> soldier wins, half the time the dead soldier wins. If the living
> soldier wins, he goes to the back of his army’s line, and the dead
> soldier is out (the living army uses dragonglass weapons, so the dead
> soldier is dead forever this time). If the dead soldier wins, he goes
> to the back of their army’s line, but this time the (formerly) living
> soldier joins him there. (Reanimation is instantaneous for this Night
> King.) The battle continues until one army is entirely eliminated.
>
> What starting sizes of the armies, living and dead, give each army a
> 50-50 chance of winning?

So we can think of this riddle as above problem. Let $m$ be the size of dead army. Let $S_i$ be (current  difference in army sizes - initial difference of army sizes). For each step $S_i$ increments by either −1 or 2. If $S_n=−m$, that means comparing to the initial state, the dead army is down by $−m$, the battle ended. If $S_n=K$, that means comparing to the initial state, the dead army is up by $K$, the battle ended. The solution is apparently $K \sim O(m^2)$. The combinatorial argument is nice, but the paper offers no stochastic explanation, which I am truly curious about.

I am fine with an approximation solution. So if we replace $X_i$ with a normal random variable with non-zero mean is fine to me too, if that helps with the estimation. But I think for a large enough $n$ this probably doesn't matter anyways.

Comment: consider the MGF $E\big[e^{S_n\theta}\big] = E\big[e^{X_1\theta}\big]^n$  and select  unique $\theta^* \neq 0$ such that $E\big[e^{X_1\theta^*}\big]=1$ (which exists for reasons of convexity and boundedness).  Now $Z_n := \prod_{k=1}^n e^{\theta^* X_k}$ and you have a product form martingale.  Apply martingale stopping theorem and you'll get useable bounds... your problem suffers from overshoots on the right so you'll have to refine the bounds somewhat.  If you are familiar with martingales you should be able to complete this yourself; if you aren't then a full solution won't make much sense.

Comment: @user8675309 I (not OP) set a bounty for this problem -- I'm really interested in the solution. if you can kindly elaborate as an answer that would be great. To me it's particularly interesting since it's such a small modification to classical random walk but with a pretty nice answer.

Comment: @MattFrank -- the question says "For a given constant , suppose we define a stopping rule to stop when ≤− or ≥. How do we find , such that the probability of stopping at ≥ is equal to the probability of stopping at ≤−?"  Is this to be interpreted literally as exactly even probability of stopping at either threshold, or approximately, as in left barrier $\geq 0.5$ prob of being hit with threshold $K-1$ and $\leq 0.5$ with threshold $K$.

Comment: If an exact solution is required at best this gets bogged down in number theory.  E.g. a problem in between this and simple fair random walk is considering the unfair random walk on $\{0,1,...,N\}$ with prob moving right of $p\in (0,1)$, $\neq \frac{1}{2}$ and left by $1-p$.  The 'exact solution' for $N$ and starting position $i$ comes down to solving for $N,i$ such that $2\big(\frac{1-p}{p}\big)^i +\big(\frac{1-p}{p}\big)^N - 1=0$.    The issue is this is still quite simple since their are no overshoots, but it shows that solving in the case of unfair games is considerably more challenging.

Comment: To me not necessarily "exactly". An estimation that gets to the $O(m^2)$ solution in the riddle is perfectly fine too

Answer (score 2):

This is too long for a comment, but the problem you formulated is **not** equivalent to the problem in the background material. The interpretation is supposed to be that $X_i=+2$ means that a dead soldier won a duel, and $X_i=-1$ means a living soldier won. You then say that $S_n=K$ means that the dead army has won. However, if the dead army initially wins $K/2$ battles in a row, then you will have $S_{n}=2(K/2)=K$, but the dead army would not have won yet.

Here is a correct formulation. Suppose there are initially $K$ living soldiers and $m$ dead ones. Let $Y_1,Y_2,\dots$ be i.i.d. and equal to $-1$ or ${\bf +1}$ with equal probability; the event $Y_i=+1$ represents a dead soldier winning a duel, and $Y_i=-1$ means a living soldier won (**note the random walk is now symmetric**).

Let $T_n=Y_1+\dots+Y_n$. Notice that $(n+T_n)/2$ is the number of dead soldier wins, and $(n-T_n)/2)$ is the number of living soldier wins. Now, we see that:

- When $(n+T_n)/2=K$, then the dead soldiers have won $K$ duels, so they won the battle. That is, the winning condition for the dead soldiers is $T_n= 2K-n$. **Whereas you had the "target value" as a constant $K$, the target value should change over time.**
- When $T_n=-m$, then the living soldiers have reduced the dead army by $m$, so the living soldiers have won (This part is the same as your setup).

Now, I do not think there is a good "stochastic" reason why $K\sim m^2$ produces a fair fight. I do know a good reason, but it has to do with carefully analyzing the walks in the 2D plane defined by the above random process, and using the reflection principle cleverly. Unfortunately, the same reflection principle argument does not work if you approximate the discrete walk by a Brownian motion, so the argument cannot be "stochastic" alone, it needs tricky combinatorics.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of hitting $-m$ before surpassing $K$ converges to the probability of ever hitting $-m$, as $K$ increases to $+\infty$. If the latter probability is $>1/2$, then the probability of being at $-m$ at the stopping time can be made equal to $1/2$ by choosing $K>0$ sufficiently large. Whether the probability of ever hitting $-m$ is $>1/2$ depends on $m$ because of the right-ward drift.

One could get some sense of the magnitudes involved by considering the analogous problem for a Brownian motion with drift $\mu=0.5$ and diffusion coefficient $\sigma = 1.5$ (for which there are known (and googlable) formulas for the hitting probabilities). In this instance the probability of ever hitting $-m$  is $\exp(-4m/9)$ so $m<(9/4)\log 2$ is needed for the choice of $K$ to be possible, and then $K= -(9/4)\log(2-\exp(4m/9))>0$.

Answer (score -1):

If you take $K=+\infty$ and $m=some\ large\ number$, then it is more likely to go right ad infinum then to finally hit $-m$. From the central limit theorem one can deduce that on step $n$ with high probability we will be somewhere within the range $\mu n \pm c\sqrt n$, where $c$ is a constant depending on our desired confidence with which we want to make such a statement (and it also includes that $1.5$ coefficient). And $\mu n$ asymptotically grows faster than $c\sqrt n$ independently of the value of $c$, so from some point $n$ this range is never hitting negative zone.

Therefore, for large enough $m$ there is simply no such $K$. And for small $m$ I suspect you can't really find this in any better way than with Monte-Carlo simulation.

Comment: Not sure if I agree. In this problem $m$ is a constant. So it doesn't grow. For a large enough $n$, $m$ is just asymptotically zero. On the other hand this is a stopping problem. Once you hit $-m$ you don't revert back. So I think it's less static than looking at an end-state normal distribution assuming you always walk for $n$ steps.

Comment: Yes, these things are not easy to reason about intuitively. But note that $\mu$ and $c$ do not depend on $m$ here, and if $n\le m$, then we can't hit $-m$ yet. So if $m=1000$, we can take first $n=1000$ steps and show that with very high probability we are in a point, say, $200$ or more. Next we may assume that we are extremely unlucky and we will stuck in $-m$ anyway provided we are not to the right of $200$. After paying this probability, replace $m$ by $1200$ and repeat the process with even higher confidence in the confidence interval etc. In the end we should estimate

Comment: the probability of hitting that initial sticky $-m$ with some geometric progression converging to a small number, if we calculate these normal tails accurately. Alternatively we can probably paramterize the probabilities of hitting $-m$ by starting at $-m+1$, $-m+2$, $-m+3$ and write down a system of linear equations. From this system it should be clear that those probabilities are in general decreasing in geometric progression even for $K >> m$.

Comment: I edited the post and offered a bit more background in my question. Let me know if you think the formulation of my problem is off..

Comment: The site with riddle doesn't load for me, and isup.me says it is down as well.

Comment: I reproduced the riddle in the post. not sure why it didn't work for you

Comment: I don't think the post is a correct reformulation of the riddle. The net difference changes by +2 or -1, but the game ends not when the net difference achieves $-m$ or $+K$, but rather when one of the armies is defeated, which may happen in a variety of differences.

Comment: Well the army is defeated when the difference is $-m$ or $K$, comparing to the initial state, no?

Comment: If the initial army sizes are equal to $X$, and living army won, you can end up with any number of surviving alive warriors $Y\le X$: e.g. dead army first killed $X-Y$, then live army eliminated the whole dead army. What is $m$ here?

Comment: $m$ is the size of dead army. Let $S_i$ be (current difference in army sizes - initial difference of army sizes). For each step $S_i$ increments by either $-1$ or $2$. If $S_n = -m$, that means comparing to the initial state, the dead army is down by $-m$, the battle ended.  If $S_n = K$, that means comparing to the initial state, the dead army is up by $K$, the battle ended

Comment: +1 for the answer; I think this is right; @MikeZach I don't understand why you say "for large enough n, m is asymptotically 0"; is m a constant, or do you get to choose that too? Also, indeed, this random walk with drift does not model the situation; perhaps an easier way to see it is by noting that your stopped process could last arbitrarily long, but the battle described in the riddle will last only (size of dead army) + (size of live army) turns.